# I'm trying to mirror dns queries generated by TCPDUMP filter and replay them with dig or any other utility

Tags: bash, grep, awk

I'm not a very experienced script writer at all. I did find some useful hints in generating an `stdout` from `tcpdump` that generates a live feed if you will which is what I want, the problem is handling the out output and generate dig/DNS queries against another DNS server for a lab.

Give me the output I'm looking for:

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

I've tried this just testing adding the output into an array but I get nothing

```
declare -a testarr
testarr=( $(tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1)}') )
echo ${testarr[@]}
```

I've also tried

```
dig @1.1.1.1 $(tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1)}')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `$()` returns only when `tcpdump` exits, but it will never exit in your case.
You can redirect output to `xargs` command - it can run `dig` before `tcpdump` exits

example code:

```
tcpdump -nvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|awk '/A\?/{print $(NF-1);fflush()}' | xargs -n 1 dig @1.1.1.1
```

Also note, that `awk` output can be buffered, so you should flush output in your `awk` program.

Comment: this isn't working for me. I've tried to echo the output -t in case it was running in the background, I've confirmed the dns server is not getting the queries but also confirmed I can make dig queries from this test host. How can I buffer awk?

Comment: you should not buffer awk, quite the contrary - you should flush awk output, also, you should not buffer tcpdump output with `-l` flag and you should note, that grep can buffer output too. I updated my answer to not use any buffers

Comment: This seems to work: 
"sudo tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1); fflush(stdout) }' | xargs -n 1 dig @1.1.1.1" 

This puts the prompt into > :
"sudo tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null | awk ‘/A\?/{print $(NF-1); fflush()}' | xargs -n 1 dig @1.1.1.1"

I think I have what I need. Do you think this can run in a backgroup process with '%' ?

@AlexanderKudrevatykh